# Send HTTPS Request in XCode (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ssl, https

I need your help :)

I'm about changing the http request into a https request from my app. For now I have used [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service). You have to know that I am a total beginner in this area of https and ssl. I appreciate any help, really.

This is the code of my http request:

```
- (void)fetchDataFromServer{

// Create Instance
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];


// Parameter der POST Anfrage setzen
[request setPostValue:@"anything" forKey:@"app_action"];


[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]; // no certificate so far
request.delegate = self; // assign delegate
[request startAsynchronous]; // send request
```

}

That worked fine. But now I need to protect the data connection and therefore I have to use **https**.

How can I realize this need? Is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) the right thing for that and it is even supporting that? What do I need to know of the certificate in the server?

Please tell me everything you know :)

Thank you very much - you're the best.

Regards
Chris

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you're starting a new project you probably shouldn't use ASIHTTPRequest, as it is no longer being maintained by the developer.

Comment: ok thanks anyway for the tip ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certificate validation is a good thing and should nearly always be done. You do not need to disable it for HTTP requests.

There is really only one exception to this rule. If you must connect to a HTTPS web service which does not have a properly signed certificate by a trusted certificate authority, then you must to turn certificate validation off.

#### Why your web service might not have a valid certificate

1. You're being hacked! This is the reason for certificates and certificate validation.
2. The web service is running on a badly configured SSL server.
3. The certificate has expired and the server isn't being kept up.
4. The owner of the web service is too cheap to pay for having his certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority.
5. A development server that isn't exposed to the public may not be worth the trouble of getting a signed certificate.

#### How to know if the web service doesn't have a properly signed certificate

1. Visit the web service in a web browser and see if you get a certificate error.
2. Check for an invalid certificate error within your app.

#### Alternatives to turning certificate validation off

1. Get your certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority.
2. Create your own certificate authority, sign your certificate with your own certificate authority, and install your certificate authority as a trusted certificate authority on the iOS device.

Comment: Okay thank for these tips. But can you give me a code example how I can send a request with a certificate validation? Would be very very helpfil :)

Comment: Certificate validation happens automatically using an HTTPS library. You would only add code to stop it.

Comment: Oh okay so you mean the delegate callback if the server want ghe credentials. But what about encryption - does this haloen also automatically? Big Thanks

Comment: No credentials are needed for checking a server certificate. All details about the encryption methods are handled by the HTTPS library. Both of these are fully automated processes handled internally by any HTTPS library.